# Regex matching closing bracket not in quotes

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to build a regex for matching strings like

```
1.) $(Something)
2.) $(SomethingElse, ")")
3.) $(SomethingElse, $(SomethingMore), Bla)
4.) $$(NoMatch) <-- should not match
5.) $$$(ShouldMatch) <-- so basically $$ will produce $
```

in a text.

**EDIT:** The words Something, SomethingElse, NoMatch, ShouldMatch can be even other words - they are names of macros. The strings i try to match are "macro calls" which can occur in a text and should be replaced by their result. I need the regex just for syntax highlighting. A complete macro call should be highlighted. Number 3 is currently not  so import. Number 1 and 2 are required to work. It's fine if number 4 and 5 will not work like written above but that any `$(` after a `$` will not match.

Currently I have

```
(?<!\$)+\$\(([^)]*)\)
```

Which matches any `$(` if there is no leading `$`, which could be fine if I will not find another way to apply the `$$` structure.

The next step I would like to get done is to ignore the closing bracket if it is in quotes. How could I achieve this?

**EDIT** So that if I have an input like

```
Some text, doesn't matter what. And a $(MyMacro, ")") which will be replaced.
```

The complete `'$(MyMacro, ")")'` will get highlighted.

I already have this expression

```
"(?:\\\\|\\"|[^"])*"
```

for quotes including escaping of quotes. But I don't know how to apply this in a way to ignore everything between them...

P.S. I am using .NET to apply the regular expressions. So balanced groups will be supported. I just don't know how to apply all this.

Comment: What is the text that you are trying to match? I mean the specification/grammar of the text.

Comment: Something like this: $(NAME[,param1[,param2[...]]]) with param1 maybe a match itself for the same pattern or a string with ' or " or a number. For Syntaxhighlighting the details shouldn't be too important.

Comment: Details are important. Not every detail, but must be close to a spec. e.g. Do you allow escaped quote in string? Description in English usually glosses over such details. So figuring out the grammar is the first step here.

Comment: Yes I allow escaped quotes, additionaly a quote can start with " OR ' and the other quote will be ignored inside the outer quote. Submacro calls are allowed as parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an expression like this:

```
(?<! \$ )                     # not preceded by $
\$ (?: \$\$ )?                # $ or $$$
\(                            # opening (

(?>                           # non-backtracking atomic group
  (?>                         # non-backtracking atomic group
    [^"'()]+                  # literals, spaces, etc
  | " (?: [^"\\]+ | \\. )* "  # double quoted string with escapes
  | ' (?: [^'\\]+ | \\. )* '  # single quoted string with escapes
  | (?<open>       \( )       # open += 1
  | (?<close-open> \) )       # open -= 1, only if open > 0 (balancing group)
  )*
)

(?(open) (?!) )               # fail if open > 0

\)                            # final )
```

Which can be quoted as above. For example in C#:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?x)    # enable eXtended mode (ignore spaces, comments)
(?<! \$ )                       # not preceded by $
\$ (?: \$\$ )                   # $ or $$$
\(                              # opening (

(?>                             # non-backtracking atomic group
  (?>                           # non-backtracking atomic group
    [^""'()]+                   # literals, spaces, etc
  | "" (?: [^""\\]+ | \\. )* "" # double quoted string with escapes
  | '  (?: [^'\\]+ | \\. )*  '  # single quoted string with escapes
  | (?<open>       \( )         # open += 1
  | (?<close-open> \) )         # open -= 1, only if open > 0 (balancing group)
  )*
)

(?(open) (?!) )                 # fail if open > 0

\)                              # final )
");
```

Comment: That seems to work quite well. The only thing (i am testing with expresso) is that $$$(Something) will be captured complete, incl. the leading $$.

Comment: @SACO, shouldn't it be captured? `$$$(ShouldMatch)`? What is desired there? What should happen in the case of `$$$$(foo)` and `$$$$$(bar)`?

Comment: only the last $ should be included $$ basically escapes the $. So $(x) should be captured. $$(x) should not be captured. $$$(x) should be captured as $(x) and the lead $$ is ignored. $$$$(x) should not be captured because this would mean two escaped $ signs. $$$$$(x) again should just capture $(x).

Comment: @SACO, probably best would just be to capture the part you want, leaving out the possible leading `$$`. I think in .NET you could use variable length lookbehinds, but I'm not sure how well that works. Instead of `(?<! \$ ) \$ (?: \$\$ )` you could try `(?<= (?<!\$) (?:\$\$)* ) \$`. If this doesn't work use a capturing group instead.

Answer (score 1):

For the part whitout the macro as a param (1 and 2) you can do :

```
(?<!\$)+\$\(([^)]*?("[^"]*?")?)+\)
```

You can see here [here](http://rubular.com/r/4kRAq90fbw)

In the case whith the macro (3) you can do :

```
(?<!\$)+\$\(([^)]*?("[^"]*?")?(\$\([^)]*?\))?)+\)
```

But this will not work for macro containing string whith parenthesis.

You can see the result [here](http://rubular.com/r/PYuXYiGgjx)

Comment: Not bad but yes, it will not work with string containing parenthesis. This is a requirement for me...

Comment: I get: Unknown modifier '+'

Answer (score 1):

Things like this are complicated... so don't get scared of the following:

RegEx: `(?<!\$)(?:\$\$)*(\$\((?:[\w, ]+|(?>"(?:(?<=\\)"|[^"])+")|(?1)+)*\))`
Explained demo here: http://regex101.com/r/yZ5dI7

This follows all your 5 points, will match the first 3 macro types and even deeper variations with multiple `"` or macro-inside-macro only when the number of `$` prefixing it is odd.

Comment: Hm, i'm not sure why but your expression fails to match: $(ForEach, "/soap-env:Envelope/soap-env:Body/testNode", "SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE ArticleId = '{0}'
\\GO\ \"ff\"
", ".") but it should match this... Your second expression i can't get working for .net

Comment: regex101 is an amazing site

Comment: I get: Unknown modifier '('

Answer (score 0):

I recently was in search of similar regex , but decided that it would be faster to parse the text with C# than a regex as my regex skills are bad ... so i wrote [this method](https://gist.github.com/aviatrix/5100780) to remove Razor code blocks.

you can easily modify it to match your needs without complex regex expressions

Comment: It would be great to have a regex because i want to use it for syntax highlighting. I am parsing all this already in another way ;)

Comment: ah , i see , sorry i can't be of much help there :/ but would love to see the solution you come up with !

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
\$\(SomethingElse, \"|[^"\)]?\"\)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Maybe I did something wrong but this will be interpreted as: either match '$(SomethingElse, "' or any character that is not " or ) followed by ")

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand exactly what you need. You need 1 regex to match all the aforementioned outputs? Also, could you provide an example of the output only you are looking for? i.e. which strings should work and which shouldn't.

Comment: Hm, maybe my english is not good enough? The strings i try to capture are LIKE the ones listed above marked as 1.) until 5.). This strings can occure in any text. They should be highlighted. See my comment under nhahtdh under my question. Please inform me if i wrote something incorrect so that i can clear up my question.

Comment: I can suggest you use http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ in the future to start learning how to build your own regular expressions